# How to call a function after the activity animation got over in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-animation, oncreate

Hi,I am using animation for moving one activity to another. I need to call a function after the animation of the activity got over but I cant find any solution.Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Animation` class then you can attach `AnimationListener`: [setAnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setAnimationListener%28android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener%29)

`Animator` also has `AnimatorListener`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html